# Html Page structure

Tags: html, css

Can a html page be designed as

```
//some words for WWW
<html>
<body class="sss">
    //some words of WWW
    <html>
       <body class="sss">
       </body>
    </html>
</body>
</html>
```

I mean the nested html in a page. This is my first time to see it and I believe it is never favorable, but how possible and how bad it is to design a page that way ?

Comment: It is against the HTML specification I believe.

Comment: I couldn't validate that page. Also HTML comments are not as depicted.

Comment: W3C Validator: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Why would you?  Use `iframe` if you want to embed another webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
<!-- some words for WWW -->
    <html>
      <head>
          ...
      </head>
      <body class="sss">
          <iframe src="http://www.yourwebsite.com">
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use iFrame if you need to load another HTML page. This is against www standards